# How can I use a push button to change between two menu bars in PyQt5? The menu bar disappears

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pyqt, pyqt5

I have two custom QMenuBar classes `MyMenuBar0` and `MyMenuBar1`, and I'd like to switch from one menu bar to the other when a button is pushed. The problem illustrated below is that pushing the button causes the menu to disappear. How should I set things up to allow the button push to switch between the menus?

**Example 1** (working example, not using a button)

When menu bars are changed as part of the main window's `__init__` method, everything works fine.

```py
class MyMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.setMenuBar( MyMenuBar0(self) ) #first menu bar set
        self.change_menu_bar()    #successful change to the second menu bar

    def change_menu_bar(self):
        self.setMenuBar( MyMenuBar1(self) )
```

**Example 2** (problem example, trying to use a button)

When repeating the above with a button, pressing the button causes the menu to disappear.

```py
class MyMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.setMenuBar( MyMenuBar0(self) )
        button  = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        button.clicked.connect( self.button_change_menu_bar )

    def button_change_menu_bar(self, a):
        self.setMenuBar( MyMenuBar1(self) ) #causes the menu bar to disappear
```

---

Here is the complete code to reproduce the problem:

**Example 1**

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class MyMenuBar0(QtWidgets.QMenuBar):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        menu        = self.addMenu('Menu 0')
        action0     = QtWidgets.QAction('Action 0', self)
        action1     = QtWidgets.QAction('Action 1', self)
        menu.addAction(action0)
        menu.addAction(action1)


class MyMenuBar1(QtWidgets.QMenuBar):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        menu        = self.addMenu('Menu 1')
        action0     = QtWidgets.QAction('Action 2', self)
        action1     = QtWidgets.QAction('Action 3', self)
        menu.addAction(action0)
        menu.addAction(action1)


class MyMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.setMenuBar( MyMenuBar0(self) ) #first menu bar set
        self.change_menu_bar()    #successful change to the second menu bar

    def change_menu_bar(self):
        self.setMenuBar( MyMenuBar1(self) )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app    = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyMainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**Example 2**

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class MyMenuBar0(QtWidgets.QMenuBar):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        menu        = self.addMenu('Menu 0')
        action0     = QtWidgets.QAction('Action 0', self)
        action1     = QtWidgets.QAction('Action 1', self)
        menu.addAction(action0)
        menu.addAction(action1)


class MyMenuBar1(QtWidgets.QMenuBar):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        menu        = self.addMenu('Menu 1')
        action0     = QtWidgets.QAction('Action 2', self)
        action1     = QtWidgets.QAction('Action 3', self)
        menu.addAction(action0)
        menu.addAction(action1)



class MyMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.setMenuBar( MyMenuBar0(self) )
        button  = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        button.clicked.connect( self.button_change_menu_bar )

    def button_change_menu_bar(self, a):
        self.setMenuBar( MyMenuBar1(self) )  #causes the menu bar to disappear


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app    = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyMainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: try changing `button  = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)` to  `central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        button  = QtWidgets.QPushButton(central_widget)`

Comment: I tried that, but it does not solve the problem. The menu still disappears.

Answer (score -1):

You want to place both menubars into the setUI method and simplify your code. This may work for you.

```py
class MyMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.setUI()

    def setUI(self):
        self.MenuBar0 = QMenuBar()
        # ...
        self.menuBar1 = QMenuBar()
        # ...
        button  = QPushButton('Toggle')
        button.clicked.connect( self.button_change_menu_bar )

    def button_change_menu_bar(self):
        state = self.menuBar0.isVisible()
        self.menuBar0.setVisible(not state)
        self.menuBar1.setVisible(state)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this doesn't work in PyQt5. QMenuBar and QPushButton both require parent arguments. Even after adding parents, the toggle behavior doesn't work. The menu bars' visibility does not toggle.